# What is the effect of the stage directions in scene 6 of The Glass Menagerie?

Tags: symbolism, tennessee-williams, the-glass-menagerie

In Scene 6, page 50 line 27, there's the following stage direction:

> Low drums sound

when the doorbell rings and Laura is required to open the door to let Jim and Tom in. What is the effect of this sound?

Is it able to relate to the theme of fear for Laura?